# Large Number of columns, Select all takes forever

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

There are 210 columns in my table with around 10000 rows. Each row is unique and there is a primary key on the table. The thing is we always had to do select all query on the table to get data of all the sites.

Currently, the problem is it takes too much time and the data returned is around 10mb and it will be large in the future.

The table has varchar, text and date types in it.

Is there any way I can modify the structure or something to make my retrieval faster. More indexing or breaking down the table. (Although I think denormalized data is good for retrieval)

Update: "**why do wider tables slow down the query performance?**"

Thanks..!

Comment: Is there any `int` datatype? If yes then give `INDEX` them.

Comment: Tables with a lot of columns *can* be symptomatic of poor design- but not necessarily. Without more information, it's hard to advise. Denormalized data is rarely 'good for retrieval'

Comment: 210 columns in one table?! Sounds like bad table design to me. You should divide it into more tables, create some indexes on a few columns and then create a view to select the data.

Comment: @PathikVejani Randomly setting an index on a column just because it's of datatype being int is bad advice. This is [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @PathikVejani the index is applied on the primary key

Comment: @waka If I divide the table in sub table then on retrieving I had to join all the tables and had to get all the information. which I think will be slower than this.

Comment: @mohammadAli There is no generic "Silver Bullet" solution that can fix arbitrary performance problems but one thing is sure: If you get bad performance with a laughable small number like 10k rows the design is definitely bad and needs to be refactored.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks! 
But one concern needs to be cleared if I refactor the table into multiple smaller ones, then I had to select all information with Inner joins. Doesn't this approach will be slower than the prior denormalized one?

Comment: I have updated the question with more usefull findings

Comment: @mohammadAli That's why I suggested creating a view. ;)

Comment: @mohammadAli No, not necessarily because your individual tables will have indices as well. Also I'd expect this to be outer joins because wide tables tend to have a lot of NULL values.

Comment: So the problem is not getting the data from the table - but transferring that data on the wire. You have not shown the CREATE TABLE statement, you have not provided example data from your table (e.g. 2-3 actual rows) and you did not even mentioned how much time it takes to execute a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1` So I can guess that it will be getting worse when you continue adding more columns. Consider putting all TEXT fields into separate 3-column table and refer to them by the composite key PARENT_ROW_ID + PARENT_COL_ID.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks. I am doing select * from the table without any condition. Does this always result in a full table scan? Can I optimize it using anything? I have tried both InnoDB and MyISAM. I am new to my SQL and need suggestions

Comment: Well, without any condition it simply returns the whole table. When you have a condition - whether it will perform a full-table scan or use an index depends on the query and on the available indexes. In order to optimize something you need to first define the desired outcome and compare it with the current outcome.

Comment: @mohammadAli - A `PRIMARY KEY` is an `INDEX`; there is no need to be redundant.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- seeing the column names and types may give us realistic clues of what you should do.  10K*210 is not big.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. My table has int, Big int and text data types. And the scenario is we have to do select * in worst case.
What I have done is to break table into two i.e. one with int and big int types and other is text ones. And we the data in future will be above 1 Million records.
Now I have tested the int/ big int table with 0.6 Million records. It is taking 492 sec.
Is it normal? Is there any thing we can do to make data retrieval faster?

Comment: (This Question is sort of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286511/expensive-full-table-scan-on-select-all-without-condition )

Comment: @mohammadAli - Even knowing the column names might give me clues of the application, which might give me ideas of more efficient processing techniques.  I try not to look just at the _immediate_ Question, but also at the _real_ Question behind the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do wider tables slow down the query performance?

InnoDB stores "wide" tables in a different way.  Instead of having all the columns together in a single string (plus overhead, such as lengths, etc), it does the following:

- If the total of all the columns for a given row exceeds about 8KB, it will move some of the data to another ("off-record") storage area.
- Which columns are moved off-record depends on the sizes of the columns, etc.
- The details depend on the `ROW_FORMAT` chosen.
- "Off-record" is another 16KB block (or blocks).
- Later, when doing `SELECT *` (or at least fetching the off-record column(s)), it must do another disk fetch.

What to do?

- Rethink having so many columns.
- Consider "vertical partitioning", wherein you have another table(s) that contains selected `TEXT` columns.  Suggest picking groups of columns based on access patterns in your app.
- For columns that are usually quite long, consider compressing them in the client and storing into a `BLOB` instead of a `TEXT`.  Most "text" shrinks 3:1.  Blobs are sent off-record the same as Texts, however, these compressed blobs would be smaller, hence less likely to spill.
- Do more processing in SQL -- to avoid returning all the rows, or to avoid returning the full text, etc.  When blindly shoveling lots of text to a client, the network and client become a sighificant factor in the elapsed time, not just the `SELECT`, itself.

Comment: Thanks. This is the explanation I was looking for.