# Expensive full table scan on select all without condition

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

I have a wide table with 210 columns (This might be a bad structure but all data is needed every time). There is a primary type index for the primary key.

Now when I do select * from my single table without any condition. It results in a full table scan.

It says the following:
**no useable indexes were found for the table**

This also means the search range is so broad that the index is useless.

What could I do to avoid this full table scan?

Note: I need all the information every time so breaking the table will result in less performance..!

I am new to MySQL. So help would be appreciated. Thanks..!

Comment: I've never run a _" select * from my single table **without any condition** "_ and not getting a full scan. I'm not even aware that it's possible, is it? But it will recognize indexes if you do `SELECT indexed_column1, indexed_column1, FROM table`

Comment: Explain what you want to extract from the table.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. My table has int, Big int and text data types. And the scenario is we have to do select * in worst case.
What I have done is to break table into two i.e. one with int and big int types and other is text ones. And we the data in future will be above 1 Million records.
Now I have tested the int/ big int table with 0.6 Million records. It is taking 492 sec.
Is it normal? Is there any thing we can do to make data retrieval faster?

Comment: Now, explain what your client will do with a million rows -- especially if they are bulky with lots of `TEXTs`, not small `INTs`.  I ask this because it _may_ be better to do more processing in SQL, and send much less than a million rows and/or much less than 210 columns.

Comment: (This question is mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284895/large-number-of-columns-select-all-takes-forever )

Answer (score 1):

Refer below link for more details

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html

cause of full table scan is below

- The table is so small that it is faster to perform a table scan than to bother with a key lookup. This is common for tables with fewer than 10 rows and a short row length.
- There are no usable restrictions in the ON or WHERE clause for indexed columns.
- You are comparing indexed columns with constant values and MySQL has calculated (based on the index tree) that the constants cover too large a part of the table and that a table scan would be faster
- You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key value) through another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table scan would be faster.

to avoid full table scan use below:

- Use ANALYZE TABLE tbl_name to update the key distributions for the scanned table.
- Use FORCE INDEX for the scanned table to tell MySQL that table scans are very expensive compared to using the given index:

  e.g. SELECT * FROM t1, t2 FORCE INDEX (index_for_column)
  WHERE t1.col_name=t2.col_name;

Comment: Thank you! 
In my case, I am using select all with now where clause, does this always result in a full table scan? and can I optimize it?

Comment: around 7k records.

Comment: use this type SELECT * FROM t1 FORCE INDEX (index_for_column)

Comment: The goal is to speed up the query, correct?  It is rare for `FORCE INDEX` to speed up the query.  Even if it does speed it up today, it may make it slower tomorrow.